# inherit res.partner in odoo 8 always error

Tags: python-2.7, inheritance, model, odoo-8

i have problem when i tried using res.partner as the model.

my code model is like this :

```
class Master(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.partner'

    provinc = fields.Many2one(
        'provinc.relation',
        string='Provinsi',
    )

    city = fields.Many2one(
        'city.relation',
        string='city',
    )

    district = fields.Many2one(
        'kabupaten.relation',
        string='Kabupaten',
    )


    zip_code = fields.Integer(
        # 'res.partner',
        string='Zip',
    )
```

and the xml like this :

```
    <record model='ir.ui.view' id='practice_relation_res_partner'>
        <field name='name'>practice_relation_res_partner_inherit</field>
        <field name='model'>res.partner</field>
        <field name='inherit_id' ref='base.view_company_form'/>
        <field name='arch' type='xml'>
            <xpath expr="//field[@name='street']" position="after">
                <field name="provinc" />
            </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>
```

the error is :

Field `rml_footer` does not exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error is becuase you inherited wrong view for partner model in xml

> <field name='inherit_id' ref='base.view_company_form'/> is res.company view and you are working with res.partner model

## inherit partner form view

> <field name='inherit_id' ref='base.view_partner_form'/>